# How can I migrate my MariaDB from 5 to 10 on my Synology NAS?

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, database-migration, synology

I have a MariaDB 5 database running on my Synology NAS. Synology recently released MaraDB 10 in the package center. I want to transfer my database from MariaDB 5 to MariaDB 10. The database has 8 tables, only 1 of which is large at 1.2 GiB.

I have tried exporting the database as a .sql file and then importing in the new MariaDB 10 instance. This seems to partially work but does not import the whole thing. Only about 1 3rd of the big table and none of some of the tables. I have checked that the missing tables have entries in the .sql file.

Is there some utility designed specifically for this scenario? Googling this gives results for databases running on a lunix machine (which I guess Synology is) and requires shell commands. And I don't know much about Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem but I solved it.
Solve

1. Login to phpMyAdmin and create backup.
2. Stop MariaDB 5 services
3. Start MariaDB10 service
4. Logon phpMyAdmin click Import.

   CLick webstation end chose php

   settings->select php version (I have php 7) -> Advenced Setting -> Extensions and set setting

[Php setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7t4HR.png)

Restart all service (not start MariaDB5)